# Is it possible to wait for answer from window.external.Foo() call?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I am using a JavaScript within a .Net Wrapper(WebBrowser control)
I would like to run a .Net Function and wait for it to return a value for the JavaScript,
I am able to call the function from the JS but wasnt able to wait for it to return a value,
for example, my JS code is:

```
IsConnected = function()
{
        var answer = window.external.IsConnected();
};
```

My C# code is:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class JavaScriptBackEnd
{
    public bool IsConnected()
    {
        if (verifyConnection())
        {
            return true;        
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a way within either C# or JavaScript for me to block the JS function until the "IsConnected" function finishes and returns a value?

Thanks!

Comment: It _should_ block (we have lots of code that does this) - what makes you think it's not? Side note - no need for `if`, you can just `return verifyConnection();`.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the following when setting up your Web browser control (assuming webBrowser is the name of your control) :

webBrowser.ObjectForScripting = new JavaScriptBackEnd(this);

This tells the Web browser where to look for the scripts.